# I don't know why relying upon circular reference is discouraged and they are prohibited by default in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, session

I am using Spring Boot version 3.0.6. I am getting a circular reference error and I don't know why.

```
┌─────┐
|  webConfig defined in file 
↑     ↓
|  loginCheckInterceptor defined in file 
↑     ↓
|  sessionLoginService defined in file 
↑     ↓
|  generalMemberService defined in file 
└─────┘
```

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final LoginCheckInterceptor loginCheckInterceptor;
    private final LoginMemberArgumentResolver loginMemberArgumentResolver;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(loginCheckInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/members/register", "/members/sign-in", "/api/posts", "/api/posts/*");
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(loginMemberArgumentResolver);
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LoginCheckInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private final LoginService loginService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws
            Exception {
        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod && ((HandlerMethod)handler).hasMethodAnnotation(
                AuthenticationRequired.class)) {
            Long memberId = loginService.getLoginMemberId();

            if (memberId == null) {
                throw new UnAuthenticatedAccessException(ErrorCode.UNAUTHENTICATED_ACCESS);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SessionLoginService implements LoginService {

    private final HttpSession httpSession;
    private final MemberService memberService;
    public static final String MEMBER_ID = "MEMBER_ID";

    @Override
    public void login(String email, String password) {
        Member member = memberService.findByEmail(email);
        memberService.checkPassword(password, member);
        httpSession.setAttribute(MEMBER_ID, member.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void logout() {
        httpSession.removeAttribute(MEMBER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public Member getLoginMember() {
        Long memberId = (Long)httpSession.getAttribute(MEMBER_ID);
        return memberService.getMember(memberId);
    }

    @Override
    public Long getLoginMemberId() {
        return (Long)httpSession.getAttribute(MEMBER_ID);
    }
}
```

```java
public interface LoginService {
    void login(String email, String password);

    void logout();

    Member getLoginMember();

    Long getLoginMemberId();
}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GeneralMemberService implements MemberService {

    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Member register(MemberRegistrationReq request) {
        validateDuplicate(request.getEmail());
        Member member = request.toEntity(passwordEncoder);
        Member savedMember = memberRepository.save(member);
        log.info("New member registered. Email: {}, ID: {}", savedMember.getEmail(), savedMember.getId());
        return savedMember;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Member findByEmail(String email) {
        return memberRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(() -> new BlogApiException(ErrorCode.MEMBER_NOT_FOUND));
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Member getMember(Long memberId) {
        return memberRepository.findById(memberId).orElseThrow(() -> new BlogApiException(ErrorCode.MEMBER_NOT_FOUND));
    }

    @Override
    public void validateDuplicate(String email) {
        if (memberRepository.existsByEmail(email)) {
            log.warn("Failed to register. Email: {}, Reason: email already exists", email);
            throw new EmailAlreadyExistsException(ErrorCode.EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void checkPassword(String password, Member member) {
        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(password, member.getPassword())) {
            log.warn("Failed to login. Email: {}, Reason: wrong password", member.getEmail());
            throw new BlogApiException(ErrorCode.WRONG_PASSWORD);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public interface MemberService {
    Member register(MemberRegistrationReq request);

    Member findByEmail(String email);

    Member getMember(Long memberId);

    void validateDuplicate(String email);

    void checkPassword(String password, Member member);
}
```

I am using session login, without Spring Security. I tried this logic to log in with email. But how should I go about solving this situation?

I am trying to avoid setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true as much as possible.

Comment: Dependencies are injected. Hence to create some `A` that has some `B` as dependency, a `B`must exist and be injected. Now, if the `B` also requires an `A`, then the system cannot create an `A`, since no `B` is created yet, and it cannot create a `B` since no `A` is created yet. There are ways around this. I would, however, recommend to resolve the circular dependency since is indicative of an overarching, architectural problem.

Comment: Using cyclic dependencies shows that an architecture has no clear structure. If a program or it's dependencies result in circular references then you and your runtime, have no idea where to start the initialization within the loop. As @Turing85 stated, this is magnified when dependency injection is involved. You should redesign that part of your application and resolve the cyclic dependencies.

Comment: @BillMair Thanks for your help. Is it right to redesign from webConfig?